# click on box to go to the next page instead of clicking on only text

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-4, haml

I have here a code where you can click on (account) text. And this will open a next page.

I want to have: when you click on the (.box.boxAccounts) that you go the next page instead of only the text (account) The =Link_to returns the account name.

```
.features-boxed
  .container.boxContainer
    #myUL.row.features.appFunction.indexBox
      - @accounts.sort_by(&:name).each do |account|
        .col-sm-6.col-md-5.col-lg-3.item.icons
          .box.boxAccounts
            .boxInsiteAccount
              %i.fa.fa-building.iconSpaceBottom.accountIcon
              %h3.name
              = link_to account.name, account_path(account), :class => "optieTekst"
              %br/
```

Comment: What have you tried, what errors are you getting and what is not happening?  [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't you just wrap the link around the box then?

```
.features-boxed
  .container.boxContainer
    #myUL.row.features.appFunction.indexBox
      - @accounts.sort_by(&:name).each do |account|
        .col-sm-6.col-md-5.col-lg-3.item.icons
          = link_to account_path(account) do
            .box.boxAccounts
              .boxInsiteAccount
                %i.fa.fa-building.iconSpaceBottom.accountIcon
                %h3.name
                = account.name
                %br/
```

Comment: Ah yeah, totally forgot that xd My bad. Thanks though it helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

[link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) takes a block.

You can try:

```
- @accounts.sort_by(&:name).each do |account|   
  .col-sm-6.col-md-5.col-lg-3.item.icons
    = link_to account_path(account) do
      .box.boxAccounts
        .boxInsiteAccount
          %i.fa.fa-building.iconSpaceBottom.accountIcon
          %h3.name
          = account.name
          %br/
```